# Changing representation overrides to attribute driven symbology for migration to ArcGIS Pro

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, esri-production-mapping

We currently use a lot of symbology representations in our map production workflows in ArcMap and are considering moving to ArcGIS Pro, which does not support representations. Many of them will be ok to make the change using attribute-driven symbology, but I am wondering if anyone else has gone through this and has any suggestions about how to deal with representation overrides.

The override is stored as a blob, but we noticed that we can still query for null in the blob field, so I assume I can use this to pull out every feature that does in fact have an override. But then I don't have much information, if any, about what exactly was changed on each representation symbol. Is there a way to get this information out of the blob field, or some other way to extract this information from the database?

Answer (score 1):

This is something I am looking into. So far the information I have found is at this link.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/draw-layers-with-representations.htm

The relevant text is bolded below:

To make modifications to the layer's symbology, convert the representation symbology to unique values symbology. This converts all representation rules and field overrides associated with the representation to layer symbology. Before converting, you must analyze the layer to identify unsupported aspects such as overrides stored in the override blob field, shape overrides, free representations, and representation marker overrides. ***Analysis produces a log file that lists each feature with overrides. You can then use ArcMap to either manually move the overridden attributes and geometries into appropriate fields, or use the Update Override geoprocessing tool to do this.***

Comment: I have tried this but the information in the log file is limited, for example, "Shape overrides found in 13 feature(s)". I was hoping I could get a little more information about the overrides to put into an attribute field but maybe this is what I will work with.